# JPQL ManyToMany Query issue (join Class)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have table on mysql generated by ManyToMany association.
but when i run this query

```
select e from Employe e join e.listeRole c inner join c.Role r where r.IdRole = 1
```

i get this error

> 13:11:51,959 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: listEmploye of: metier.entities.Employe [select e from metier.entities.Employe e join e.listEmploye c inner join c.Role r where r.IdRole = 1]
>   13:11:51,960 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component Utilisateur for method public abstract java.util.List metier.sess.IUtilisateurLocal.RoleEmploye(): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: listEmploye of: metier.entities.Employe [select e from metier.entities.Employe e join e.listEmploye c inner join c.Role r where r.IdRole = 1]

my classes are

```
 @Entity
 public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer IdRole;
private String Intitule;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="listeRole")
private List<Employe> listEmploye=new ArrayList<Employe>();

public Integer getIdRole() {
    return IdRole;
}

public void setIdRole(Integer idRole) {
    IdRole = idRole;
}

public String getIntitule() {
    return Intitule;
}

public void setIntitule(String intitule) {
    Intitule = intitule;
}

public List<Employe> getListEmploye() {
    return listEmploye;
}

public void setListEmploye(List<Employe> listEmploye) {
    this.listEmploye = listEmploye;
}

public Role(String intitule) {
    super();
    Intitule = intitule;
}


public Role() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="employe")
public class Employe extends Utilisateur{
private String TypeEmploye;
private Integer authentification;
private Date logindate;
private Date logoutDate;    
//Employe class
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> listeRole=new ArrayList<Role>();
public String getTypeEmploye() {
    return TypeEmploye;
}
public void setTypeEmploye(String typeEmploye) {
    TypeEmploye = typeEmploye;
}
public Integer getAuthentification() {
    return authentification;
}
public Date getLogindate() {
    return logindate;
}
public void setLogindate(Date logindate) {
    this.logindate = logindate;
}
public Date getLogoutDate() {
    return logoutDate;
}
public void setLogoutDate(Date logoutDate) {
    this.logoutDate = logoutDate;
}
public void setAuthentification(Integer authentification) {
    this.authentification = authentification;
}
public List<Role> getListeRole() {
    return listeRole;
}
public void setListeRole(List<Role> listeRole) {
    this.listeRole = listeRole;
}
public Employe(String username, String password, String email,
        boolean statut, String typeEmploye, Integer authentification,
        List<Role> listeRole) {
    super(username, password, email, statut);
    TypeEmploye = typeEmploye;
    this.authentification = authentification;
    this.listeRole = listeRole;
}
public Employe() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}}
```

thanks for you help

Comment: When you ask for sql query problems, Please post your Schema also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a many to many you should define a jointable on the owning side as follows:

```
 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "emp_roles", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id",
               referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
               referencedColumnName = "id")})
  private List<Role> listeRole;
```

That is the employee entity in your case that this mapping should be on.

Why do you have a reference from Role to employee? I dont see why you would ever want to use it so I suggest you change that bidirectional mapping to a unidirectional one ( so just drop the employees list in the role entity)

Comment: Thank you so much you are a life saver

Comment: No problem. I have 1 more remark for your code though if you would hear me out.. dont EAGER fetch the list of roles. It sreally bad practice to do that.

Comment: Thank you alot for your remarks ive changed it to lazy

Comment: If you ever need to use it just make sure that you initialize it while the objects are still managed..theres a lot of documentation for that :) cheers